# Aligning buttons to center in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I am trying to set the buttons to the center using the `Box.createHorizontalStrut()` method. However if I use `this.getWidth()/2` is does not work. How can I do to center it in the frame.

### Code

```
package ch17;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Q17_1 extends JFrame{
    JButton left = new JButton("<=");
    JButton right = new JButton("=>");
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("Red");
    JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
    JRadioButton rb3 = new JRadioButton("White");
    JRadioButton rb4 = new JRadioButton("Gray");
    JRadioButton rb5 = new JRadioButton("Green");
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    Message m = new Message("Welcome to Java");
    public Q17_1(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Select Message Panel Background"));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(rb1);group.add(rb2);group.add(rb3);group.add(rb4);group.add(rb5);
        rb1.setMnemonic('R');rb2.setMnemonic('Y');rb3.setMnemonic('W');rb4.setMnemonic('G');
        rb5.setMnemonic('N');
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5,5,5));
        p1.add(rb1);p1.add(rb2);p1.add(rb3);p1.add(rb4);p1.add(rb5);
        p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        add(p1);
        add(m);
        p2.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(250));
        p2.add(left); 
        p2.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        p2.add(right); 

        add(p2);
        
        left.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
            m.moveLeft();
            repaint();
        });
        
        right.addActionListener((ActionEvent)-> {
            m.moveRight();
            repaint();
        });
        
        rb1.addActionListener(m);
        rb2.addActionListener(m);
        rb3.addActionListener(m);
        rb4.addActionListener(m);
        rb5.addActionListener(m);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q17_1 frame = new Q17_1();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
  
}
```

I have tried, `this.getWidth()/2`, `p2.getWidth()/2`, etc. However they don't work and the buttons are still starting from the beginning of the left side.

Comment: Use a combination of `BorderLayout` and `FlowLayout`

Comment: But If I want to use BoxLayout for practice for p2. What should I put for the arguments in order to center the buttons???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `Borderlayout`, `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout`

For summary:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//...
p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(m);
//...
add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The reason I might consider using `BorderLayout` of `GridLayout` for the core layout is it will give all the remaining space to the component in the `CENTER` position.  This might not be what you want, but it's why I've used it.

Both `GridBagLayout` and `FlowLayout` will layout it's containers around the centre of the container, `GridBagLayout` doing it vertically and horizontally, `FlowLayout` doing it only horizontally (by default)

[image: Buttons]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Q17_1 extends JFrame {

    JButton left = new JButton("<=");
    JButton right = new JButton("=>");
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("Red");
    JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
    JRadioButton rb3 = new JRadioButton("White");
    JRadioButton rb4 = new JRadioButton("Gray");
    JRadioButton rb5 = new JRadioButton("Green");
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel m = new JLabel("Welcome to Java");
//  Message m = new Message("Welcome to Java");

    public Q17_1() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Select Message Panel Background"));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(rb1);
        group.add(rb2);
        group.add(rb3);
        group.add(rb4);
        group.add(rb5);
        rb1.setMnemonic('R');
        rb2.setMnemonic('Y');
        rb3.setMnemonic('W');
        rb4.setMnemonic('G');
        rb5.setMnemonic('N');

        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5, 5, 5));
        p1.add(rb1);
        p1.add(rb2);
        p1.add(rb3);
        p1.add(rb4);
        p1.add(rb5);

        p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(m);
        p2.add(left);
        p2.add(right);

        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        left.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
//          m.moveLeft();
//          repaint();
        });

        right.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
//          m.moveRight();
//          repaint();
        });

//      rb1.addActionListener(m);
//      rb2.addActionListener(m);
//      rb3.addActionListener(m);
//      rb4.addActionListener(m);
//      rb5.addActionListener(m);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q17_1 frame = new Q17_1();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

> But If I want to use BoxLayout for practice for p2. What should I put for the arguments in order to center the buttons???

Because the container's size dynamic, you could use some horizontal glue instead

```
    p2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    p2.add(left);
    p2.add(right);
    p2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Comment: I wanted to practice boxlayout back then. but when trying to get the width of the panel, it didn't work

Comment: The `width` of the panel won't be know until it's laid out.  You have a catch 22 problem.  Instead, apply a dynamic filler to the container that will allow it to occupy the remainder of the space left over after the component's space is calculated.  Remember, the size of any container is not only it's contents, but also how it might be laid out in the parent container...

Comment: Try and avoid working in absolutes, it will always burn you

Comment: Sorry what does it mean by absolutes? So when should I use the BoxLayout???  Also, If I were to use boxLayout and want to do the following what should i do?

Comment: <random space to display the buttons >      Button1 Button2

Comment: I want to make it such that when the window is maximized, the button will move in propertion

Comment: You're apply absolute values to the filler.  How do you know what values to feed it when you don't know the size of the container or the amount of space the contents will need?  You should use `BoxLayout` when it achieves the job you want.  As I said, both `FlowLayout` AND `GridBagLayout` are capable of providing the result you're looking for, with much less issues

Comment: *"I want to make it such that when the window is maximized, the button will move in propertion "* - Proportionally to what?  They will remain in the centre?  Aligned to an edge?  Horizontal glue will do that much...

Comment: Sorry can you provide an example of GridBagLayout in this case? Thank you :)

Comment: In my first example, change `p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` to `p2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` :)

Comment: I thought the gridBadLayout is working only if we provide the gridbadconstraints

Comment: Nope, if you don't supply constraints, i kind of acts like FlowLayout, but centres vertically and horizontally